# Syntax error - cannot find what is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot find what is wrong here, especially at line `1`.

I got the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':username' at line 1

```
include ("params.php");
include ("$config");

$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
extract($_POST);

try {
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
    $msg = 'YOU ARE NOT REGISTERED !';
}
elseif ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    $msg = 'WELCOME ' . $username . ' !';
}
else {
    $msg = 'SOMETHING WRONG - MORE THAN ONE USER';
}
echo $msg;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE members SET logged = :logged WHERE username = :username') ;
$stmt->execute(array(
':logged' => 1,
':username' => $username,
));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: firstly, why are you using `stripslashes()`? you're using a prepared statement, and which api are you using to connect with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
```

but you must first `prepare` a statement, as you do in the second statement at

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE members SET logged = :logged WHERE username = :username') ;
$stmt->execute(array(
':logged' => 1,
':username' => $username,
));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare that statement. You have an example below in your own code, where you prepare a query providing values for placeholders `:logged` and `:username`.  But up above you fail to do so with the :username placeholder, which is why you're getting that error.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php gives another example of the process down towards the bottom.